# Is there a Python function to mark the beginning and end of sentences with a specific character after tokenizing?

Tags: python, tokenize

with `tokenize` I know you can split text into individual words, but I am confused on how to add characters to indicate the beginning and end of sentences after tokenizing. In my case I want to put `^` to indicate the beginning of the sentence and `$` to indicate the end of the sentence. I am asking because I am trying to implement bigram probability models and this is for a school assignment, which is why this is a reinvent the wheel problem.

Comment: It would help if you would add to your question the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`tokenize` is a part of python distribution, and intended to parse python source code. Is this actually a good tool for your problem? Have you tried `nltk`?